# Parse Faraday Response body as Nokogiri Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, mechanize, faraday

I have considered switching from Mechanize to Faraday, since I am making a lot of requests and it seems to be a lot quicker. What I couldn't find out, however, is if it is possible to parse the response body as an Nokogiri Object. The Mechanize way to do so is as follows:

```
Mechanize.new.get(url).parser
```

How can that be achieved using Faraday instead of Mechanize?

Comment: did you tried open-uri? first of all `require 'nokogiri'` and `require 'open-uri'`. And then `noko_obj = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)) `

Comment: It's not necessary to use `require 'nokogiri'`. Mechanize does it automatically, since it uses Nokogiri internally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same result can be achieved by doing:

```
site = Faraday.new.get('http://www.mysite.com').body
nokogiri_object = Nokogiri::HTML(site)
```

Comment: "Since this only looks at the sites body it theoretically be faster." Huh? Faster compared to what?